# Recorrer array en controller laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, json, array

Quiero recorrer un array que me llega desde la view y hacer insert a base de datos pero sólo me ingresa el último array.

Este es el array que envío (lo envío como json y lo convierto en array en el controlador)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Controlador donde llegar el array:

```
$producto= new producto();
$productos=json_decode($request->productos);

        // NO ME RECORRE EL ARRAY, SÓLO ME MUESTRA EL ÚLTIMO INGRESADO
  /*   foreach ($productos as $p) {
        $array=[
            'codigo'=>$p->codigo,
            'cantidad'=>$p->cantidad,
            'descripcion'=>$p->descripcion,
            'valor'=>$p->valor,
            'total'=>($p->valor * $p->cantidad),
            'fecha'=> $p->fecha,
        ];
    } */

    //SI DEJO PRODUCTOS[$I] ME AGREGA EL ÚLTIMO ARRAY, SI DEJO PRODUCTOS[$J] 
      ME AGREGA EL PRIMER ARRAY
    $j=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($productos);$i++){

        $producto->codigo=$productos[$i]->codigo;
        $producto->cantidad=$productos[$i]->cantidad;
        $producto->descripcion=$productos[$i]->descripcion;
        $producto->valor=$productos[$i]->valor;
        $producto->total=($productos[$i]->cantidad * $productos[$i]->valor);
        $producto->fecha=$productos[$i]->fecha;
        $producto->save();
        $j++;
    }
```

He intentado con varios métodos que he buscando acá en la página pero no he llegado a una solución. Ojalá puedan ayudarme.

Comment: La instancio en $producto= new producto();

Comment: @BetaM  me funcionó colocando la instancia dentro del for jajajaj, era tan simple y no podía verlo. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución era tan simple como instanciar el modelo de producto dentro del ciclo for:

```
$productos=json_decode($request->productos);
    for($i=0;$i<count($productos);$i++){

        $producto= new producto();
        $producto->codigo=$productos[$i]->codigo;
        $producto->cantidad=$productos[$i]->cantidad;
        $producto->descripcion=$productos[$i]->descripcion;
        $producto->valor=$productos[$i]->valor;
        $producto->total=($productos[$i]->cantidad * $productos[$i]->valor);
        $producto->fecha=$productos[$i]->fecha;
        $producto->save();
    }
```

De esa manera me inserta todos los valores que estén pasando en el array a la base de datos.

Comment: Si, debo esperar 2 días y la marcaré como aceptada. Muchas gracias nuevamente!